# Spring MVC Form static text

Tags: java, forms, spring

I'm trying to make form with Spring MVC for editing some object. Some fields of this object are set at the moment of creation and then can not be edited, so they must be shown on editing form like plain text, not like an input.
I was very suprised when I didn't find smth like spring:output in spring forms tag library. How can do it? Please help :)
Here is the code of my form:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

    <h1><spring:message code="Information" /></h1>

    <form:form commandName="shop" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="ShopCompanyName"/>
                <td colspan="2">**HERE MUST BE A STATIC TEXT 
FILLED WITH THE VALUE OF SOME FIELD FROM OBJECT**</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><h2><spring:message code="Contacts"/></h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="ShopUserLN"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="user.lastName"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="user.lastName" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="ShopUserFN"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="user.firstName"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="user.firstName" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="ShopUserMN"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="user.middleName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="ShopUserPhone"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="user.phone"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="user.phone" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:out value="${someObject.someProperty}"/>
```

Or even

```
${someObject.someProperty}
```

if XML-escaping is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks <c:out value="${someObject.someProperty}"/> worked! But will it then submit this field value to controller when form will be submitted?

Comment: No. This is static text, as you asked. If you want to submit it (but why not simply regenerate it at server-side), then you need a hidden form field.

Comment: To regenerate it on server side I will have to get this object from database by id again, update all editable fileds in retrieved object with submitted object's values and then save the updated object..that is not good I think..Will it be a good approach to use one static field to show data and one hidden field to subnit it to server when the whole object is saved, so it wouldn't be empty?

Comment: Getting the value from database again is a better approach. If the field is not modifiable, you should not let the user modify it. Any script kiddie could launch Firebug, edit the value of the hidden field, and submit whatever he wants.

Comment: You are right. But if the logic of form will be modified, for example,  if some new fields will be added to the object. I'll have to modify not only the form and the object itself, but also the form processing logic, exactly process of updating old object with submitted values. Is it normal and the only aproach for Spring MVC?

Comment: This can be automated using a ModelAttribute. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: As I know ModeAttribute maps object that represented with the form to my entity class. But how can it help me in my situation. Please be kindly to explain what you mean.

Comment: You add a method which gets the `SomeObject` to edit by ID, and annotate it with `ModelAttribute`. This makes Spring call the method automatically and add the `SomeObject` instance to edit to the model. Then you add an argument of type `SomeObject` to the `processSubmit()` method, also annotated with `ModelAttribute`. Spring will see that the object is already in the model, and will automatically populate it using the request parameters. It's all explained in the link I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

if you have separated your output to a tagfile you can use spring data binding and the status object, to avoid a handover of the form name or object "shop":

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/path/to/tag"%>

<form:form commandName="shop" method="POST">
    <my:formFieldFixed path="name"/>
</form>
```

and in the /path/to/tag/formFieldFixed.tag file

```
<%@ attribute name="path" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:bind path="${path}">
    <span>${status.value}</span>
</spring:bind>
```

With bindings like this you can also separate your form-errors from your form-container, and many things more. See an example here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create a multiple fields in one line in Spring, then you might used the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="first_name">First Name:</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="first_name" /></td>

    <td><form:label path="last_name">Last Name:</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="last_name" /></td>
</tr>
```

This is the easiest way to create a form fields in single line...

Comment: The question is "How to place plain text, not input."